# Javascript parseInt with radix 16 issue

Tags: javascript, hex, parseint, radix

The alert statement  `alert(parseInt("0x00C02700010004E9",16));` incorrectly displays 54086076498707690 instead of the correct value 54086076498707689. Please notice the last two digits!!

Could anyone shed some light on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Javascript is not accurate to that many digits! See: [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)