# Stange functionality in javascript numbers

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)

I am experiencing some strange behavior when working with numbers in javascript. When I use the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:console.log({'id':9200000000032337}.id);"> CLICK HERE </a>
```

I get the number 920000000003233**6** in my console. I think it most be something with rounding or max values for numbers, but I don't understand it completely. Anyone?

Comment: what code? is clearly enough!

Comment: @sunleo, the code is only the html I have put in the question, the result is in the console if you click the <a> tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not a Javascript expert, but it sounds like your number is being stored as an IEEE-754 64-bit floating point number. Certainly that's what I get from C# code which will display the exact value of a `double`:

```
double d = 9200000000032337;
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(d));
```

(Using my own `DoubleConverter` class.) My output is the same as yours: 9200000000032336

Floating point values only ever hold a certain number of significant digits accurately - and when the numbers get high enough, even integers can't be stored exactly.

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) seems to confirm this:

> **4.3.19**
>   Number value
>   primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value

and from section 7.8.3 (numeric literals):

> A numeric literal stands for a value of the Number type. This value is determined in two steps: first, a 
>   mathematical value (MV) is derived from the literal; second, this mathematical value is rounded as described 
>   below.

Section 8.5 contains more details.

Comment: thats exactly what it is. as bigger the number, as lower is the precision.