# java How to get a long as UID

Tags: java, uuid

I have method that creates elasticsearch documents. It uses OpenStreetMap Object IDs as the ES document ID. I now also want to add other documents that do not have an OSM id.

I cannot use a UUID generator since the method requires a long.

What is the best way to get a "pseudo" UUID with a long type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate unique Long using UUID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184820/how-to-generate-unique-long-using-uuid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve a long UID generating a random sequence of 64bit, i.e. using AtomicLong().

> [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) is a long value that may be updated atomically.  An
>   AtomicLong is used in applications such as atomically incremented
>   sequence numbers

```
private static final AtomicLong TS = new AtomicLong();
public static long getUniqueTimestamp() {
    return TS.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Each call of getUniqueTimestamp() returns a unique id for the process, starting from 0.

You can start from an higher value initializing Atomic with current time:

```
private static final AtomicLong TS = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);
```

## Note

this is not an **UNIVERSAL** UID, just a UID!

Comment: Hopefully nobody or no automated sync will change the server date/time.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

public class RandomLong {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long id = Long.parseLong(RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(18));
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
    }

}
```

It ensures positive longs, which is ideal for IDs.

Here is another answer that puts more emphasis on uniqueness by using nano time and an atomic counter.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class UniqueLong {


    static AtomicInteger atom = new AtomicInteger(0);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long id = Long.parseLong(System.nanoTime() + "" + (atom.getAndIncrement() % 1_000));
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
    }

}
```