# Decimal values gets round off automatically

Tags: javascript, decimal

When i assign `99999999999.999999` to a variable, it gets round off to 100000000000,
and when i remove one `9` from the value , the last digit becomes 8.

like,

```
9999999999.999999 = 9999999999.999998
99999999999.99999 = 99999999999.99998
```

kindly help me to resolve this

Comment: the floating piont error

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: This is because how numbers are saved on a computer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format You can use big decimal for such purposes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: @verbose-mode: This is javascript not java, they cannot use BigDecimal (not that java version anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Numbers in ECMAScript (Javascript) are internally represented by double-precision floating-point. When setting a number, it actually is assigned the nearest representable double-precision value, which is 100000000000 in this case.

See [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)