# JSON Response Long is Rounded or Corrupted

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am sending JSON from the server to client side. The JSON contains a `long`.

It appears that the number is being rounded or something because:

- The server side number sent is:     `1036647050030089506`
- The client side number received is: `1036647050030089500`

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Server side code:

```
Post["team", true] = async (parameters, ct) =>
{
    var team = this.Bind<Team>();
    team.Id = 1036647050030089506;

    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + team.Id);
    return Response.AsJson(team);
};
```

Client side code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/team',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert("Response: " + response.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Woah, no... don't do that. The response is definitely json. The problem here is that, even though JSON can handle indefinitely large numbers, JavaScript can't, so you're encountering loss-of-precision issues when it tries to convert your very large value into a Float. Please se @JohnnyFun's answer for more details there.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you'll want to send it as a string. See this question for more details about [how js handles big ol' numbas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript). Spoiler alert: poorly...but I still love you javascript...still love you.

Comment: +1, this is correct. To help illustrate, try the following: `var num = 1036647050030089506; console.log(num);`