# Parse JSON with large numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, json, 64-bit, long-integer

I'm getting a `JSON` object that includes a `long` type value from an API response.
Since javascript can't handle 64bit numbers, when executing `JSON.parse` on the response it rounds the number to the maximum value javascript can handle.

**API response:**

```
    {
       "subject": "subjectTitle",
       "longNumberKey": 7356270823847851521,
    }
```

When parsing this object to `JSON`, `longNumberKey` value would be `7356270823847852000` instead of `7356270823847851521`.
A solution would be to represent this value as a `string` but I can't control the API response for that.

Comment: What should it return instead? Javascript numbers simply don't have enough precision to represent that number accurately.

Comment: I know that, but I need to display this value accurately, I don't need to do any arithmetic operations with this number.

Comment: Javascript can't store numbers like this. It doesn't matter what you want to do with it.

Comment: We both know this fact. The question is what would be a solution for that. Do you have any idea ? Maybe other approach than JSON.parse ?

Comment: Write your own, custom JSON parser that parses numbers as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought of. Is the native Parse function code accessible to view ?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's built-in code of the browser.

Comment: @Barmar curious what approach would be...even in a `replacer` wouldn't number get lost?

Comment: **json-bignum** https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bignum see below

Comment: @charlietfl If it returns numbers as strings, it shouldn't lose anything.

Comment: @Barmar ok..so in other words because it is still in a json string it would be considered string without quotes in `replacer`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript

Comment: @charlietfl I don't know what you mean by `replacer`.

Comment: @Barmar ..oops meant `reviver` as in `JSON.parse(string, reviver)`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a reviver, I was suggesting `function myJSONparse(string) { ... }`

Comment: A reviver will not help, it gets the parsed values.
Anyway, it seems like the `json-bignum` library provides a solution to my case. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

----->  **json-bignum** **https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bignum** <------ JSON parser !

GMP (GNU multiple precision) with javascript https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum/blob/master/src/gmp-example.html

**gmp.js** https://github.com/kripken/gmp.js?MobileOptOut=1

Comment: Does it have a JSON parser? He doesn't need to do arithmetic on the numbers, he just needs to parse the JSON.