# Very strange error in console.log of Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I posted a related question here: [Error when removing duplicates from Javascript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441021/error-when-removing-duplicates-from-javascript-array) 
but there's a part of it that might need its own question, so I'll ask it here.

I have this code:

```js
var myArray = [621608617992776, 10156938936550295];
console.log(myArray);
```

It's a simple array with two numbers.
However, when I run the code with the console open. It's increasing the second number by 1.

So instead of console.logging `[621608617992776, 10156938936550295]`

It's console.logging `[621608617992776, 10156938936550296]`

Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: Don't expect anything to work properly when using numbers greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Hi @Gothdo thanks for your reply. Do you have any advice on how to get around this problem? Is converting the integers to strings the only way?

Comment: Take a look at [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/) library.