# Query against array of long types returns nothing

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a cluster with documents, with one field being an array of long types. Below is an example value of this field:

```
"request_categories": [
    150848602323501540,
    150847029425938900
],
```

When I query the field, it does not return anything. Below is the query.

```
GET service_alias/service/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "request_categories" : 150848602323501540
    }
  }
}
```

This data field is indexed. I have no problems querying other data fields. Anything that I may have missed? Thanks!

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952262/elasticsearch-max-length-of-mapping-type-long/38952540#38952540

Comment: thanks. this doesn't seem to be the case for me.