# Python Elasticsearch-DSL - aggregations sum - return float result

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to sum revenue from orders,
But the **results are** in float **.6299743652344**

Any idea why?

**Field in data is .00**

("grand_total": 84.5)

```
s = Search(using=ES, index='orders')
s = s[:0]
s.aggs.metric('rev', 'sum', field='grand_total')
res = s.execute()
return res.aggs.rev.value
```

result:

`Response: {'rev': {'value': 3195.6299743652344}}`

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53480867/4604579 (hint: float number precision in JS)

Comment: Didn't help, but thank you.

Comment: How come? It is most likely a precision issue

Comment: It's doesn't makes sense, the numbers are rounded. the sum should be rounded to.

Comment: Let's take `84.1 * 84.6` which should give you `7114.86`, if you try to compute that in JavaScript (Node.js console, browser dev tools, etc), you'll get `7114.859999999999`

Comment: Same thing with `81.1 + 82.8`, it should give you `163.9`, yet in JS it yields `163.89999999999998`

Comment: I understand that this is the response in JS, still it's weird that ElasticSearch SUM results is not rounded.

Comment: The reason is simple: The response is in JSON. This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709595/why-would-you-use-a-string-in-json-to-represent-a-decimal-number