# Elasticsearch: Number is changed after inserting it

Tags: elasticsearch

When I add the number  "1xx41401494081287" (xx is instead of two figures), the result is 
"1xx41401494081288". It ends up like the number +1. So with a ..88 instead of ..87

When I add the number 1xx41401494081290, the result isn’t changed. So the field-length should be ok.

The type of the field is ‘long’. Am i missing something?

I don’t use specifiek fieldnames or something. It’s already when i enter:
POST testname/testype
{
"Testname":1xx41401494081287
}

Comment: You're probably running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952262/elasticsearch-max-length-of-mapping-type-long/38952540#38952540

Comment: Thnx! had tried all kinds of search options. Now we can proceed.

Comment: Solution was indeed: saving the number as a string.