# How to set an array of integers to a spreadsheet cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add some values from an array to a cell using `Google Script` but there are additional `,` added and the last number is wrong...

Here is my code:

```
var array = [36776, 37245, 45948, 48877];
ss.getRange(5,11).setValue(array.join());
```

And the content of that cell is `36,776,372,454,594,800,00` instead of `36776, 37245, 45948, 48877`

Comment: Your cell has a number format or custom format?

Comment: I didn't modify the cell format...it has the default format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is due to *double-precision floating-point* type of number javascript uses.

When you join those numbers and enter in a cell, I guess google spread Sheet is considering this string (which only contains number and comma) a number and converting this string to number. At this point, this is what is happening: [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript).

If you want to keep it as you want, add some non numeric value that is not supposed to be in number convention i.e add quotations "36776,37245,45948,48877"

```
sheet.getRange(5,11).setValue('"' + array.join() + '"');
```

Or remove the comma entirely to keep the numbers safe from rounding automatically.

```
sheet.getRange(5,11).setValue(array.join().replace(/,/g, ""));
```