# JavaScript number automatically "rounded"

Tags: javascript

Odd issue:

I enter a very large number into the console, for instance `883036583895237057` and it returns `883036583895237100`, just `43` more.

What's happening?

[image]

Comment: Because at that scale, that's the number an IEEE-754 double-precision floating point value can hold that's nearest to the number you entered. The highest number that you can add 1 to and get he next integer up is 9007199254740991 (unsurprisingly, 9007199254740991 + 1 = 9007199254740992); after that, adding just 1 won't get you to the next integer (9007199254740992 + 1 = 9007199254740992!).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript is a better dupe target.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I don’t have the gold badge for JS, unfortunately…