# Maximum number size different with trailing zeros

Tags: javascript

I have a number `n` which is 16 digits long (`1111111111111111`). When I add another `1` to this number (making it `11111111111111111`, 17 digits long) it is displayed as `11111111111111112`.

This is understandable because it is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, however if I add a `0` instead (making it `11111111111111110`, still 17 digits long), the number is displayed correctly as `11111111111111110`.

```
let a = 11111111111111111;
let b = 11111111111111110;

console.log(a, b); // 11111111111111112 11111111111111110
```

The behaviour above occurs with any final digit, apart from `0`. What is the reason for this difference in behaviour?

---

I have looked at ["Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379934/1916362), but that doesn't explain why it is rounded when a non-zero number is added, and not when a zero is added.

Comment: looks like a integer rounding problem in javascript

Comment: Not sure what’s not understandable about this behavior. Try appending a `2`. It’s not rounded to a different number either. As the answers in the duplicate target state, it’s _rounded_ if a number can’t be represented otherwise. Even numbers _can_ be represented at this size. Yet larger numbers can only represent every fourth, then every eighth number etc. It’s not about zero vs. non-zero.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox that makes sense. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JamesMonger I’d argue, the answers from the other question explain that sufficiently already, so no.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Javascript, numbers are stored as double precision floating point numbers. Large integers exceed the precision range of doubles, so they become inaccurate.