# AngularJS give me rounded big number

Tags: angularjs, numbers, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use my AngularJS application to display Twitter account, and big account ID give me a rounded number such as :

**748598350317031424** give me **748598350317031400** when displayed on page with *ng-repeat*.

Have you got an idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript

Comment: It's Laravel who's return me the rounded ID.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to javascript JSON roundup. When id is set to `748598350317031424`, it actually assigned to the nearest representable double-precision value, which is `748598350317031400`. Because Numbers in ECMAScript are internally represented double-precision floating point.

check [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) for the details.

I once stuck in a situation like that and what I did was something that I'm not proud of. But you can send `XMLHttpRequest` that `responseType='text'`(check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText)) which will return the whole json response as string. now since the id comes as string value json roundup will not occur. then you can split the json by property name and get the value.  As i said before this is not the best way to do this. But I'm hoping this will useful to someone.