# Why the number 9094504735860991 is translated to 9094504735860992 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var num = 9094504735860991;
console.log(num); // 9094504735860992
```

Now I set a variable named num equals to 9094504735860991,but when logged, it changed to 9094504735860992.

Number.MAX_VALUE => 2^53 - 1 === 9007199254740000, however 9094504735860991 < 9007199254740000.

Comment: you mean **9094504735860991 > 9007199254740000** right?

Comment: We'd need to see some code for more context into why this is happening.

Comment: Are you sure that's Number.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: Short answer: Because beyond `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` (`9007199254740991`), the IEEE-754 floating-point format can no longer represent every consecutive integer. `9007199254740991 + 1` is `9007199254740992`, but `9007199254740992 + 1` is also ``9007199254740992` because `9007199254740993` cannot be represented. The next that can be is `9007199254740994`. Long answer: See the linked question's answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Please post this as an answer. Would help others!!

Comment: @Pugazh: Thanks. :-) Maybe I'll update [my answer to the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1379973/157247), which looks like it could be clearer via incorporating some of my comment above.

Comment: Ugh, I wish I could fix the error in my comment above. `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1` is `9007199254740992`, not `9007199254740991`, `900719925474099` **is** `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.