# Sending var from php to nodejs with minimist

Tags: php, node.js, discord.js

Trying to get PHP to send a variable to Node.js, but it changes the variable
in my PHP file I have.

```
exec("node myscript.js --userid=$userid &", $output);
```

the `$userid` in my test is `346236693579300867`.
In my Nodejs file I have:

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
discord.sendMessage("Welcome " + "<@" + argv.userid + ">" );
```

In Node.js `userid = 346236693579300860`. It keeps changing the last digit. Even if I do

```
exec("node myscript.js --userid=346236693579300867 &", $output);
```

The output is still `346236693579300860`.

What am I doing wrong?
Am new to Node.js and PHP so am still learning.
Cheers

Comment: No expert but did you try `--userid="346236693579300867"`

Comment: Yeah, Have tried that one as well. Does the same thing. Seems to be the length of the number after playing around just then. If I do 3462366935793008, it shows the correct number, as soon as I add the next number "6" onto it. I get 34623669357930090.

Comment: Is the NodeJS just needed to send that message?
You could use a PHP Discord Library to send that message

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/restcord/restcord

Comment: Not great with php, which is why Im using nodejs as my bot is coded in it. the php I have is just for a callback. But might have to look into it. Might be the easiest way.

Comment: I'm just looking at the source of minimist: https://github.com/substack/minimist/blob/master/index.js#L59, it uses Number() javascript method, which will cast it. `console.log(Number('346236693579300867'));` :/

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript you could work around this by prepending a string to it for example: `--userid="_346236693579300867"`, so the minimist code thinks its a string, then in your node code trim off the `_`.