# Number.prototype.toString() is broken for large numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an integer to number with specific base. In this case it's 36.

So [as documentation states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) I do `myNumber.toString(36)`.

Here are the results:

```js
console.log((12345678901234566).toString(36));
console.log((12345678901234567).toString(36));
console.log((12345678901234568).toString(36));
console.log((12345678901234569).toString(36));
console.log((12345678901234570).toString(36));
console.log((12345678901234571).toString(36));
```

as you can see there's something off because the output is not unique.

From what I've found `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991` and my numbers exceed that value so I believe that's why it's treated differently

It's a shame that it's not stated anywhere in the documentation that there are some boundaries. Maybe it's common knowledge, I don't know.

Any ideas how to approach this issue for bigger numbers?

I can see that [here](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-36-conversion.html) it's implemented wrongly (as in my example) and [here](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-us/numbers/39-13/base-36-base-10/) correctly  but I don't know the logic behind it.

Comment: `Maybe it's common knowledge`  Most native types of any programming language have some form of limits,.. But what you can do is use a third party lib to handle big number,.. There are lots of them out there, here is one I just googled.  https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: See [Large numbers erroneously rounded in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1379934/4642212).

Comment: Those numbers would surprise you even if you logged them in base 10 ;) Read on MDN about [safe integers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger).