# parseInt and Number casting result in different number from string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a number from a string but it's returning the wrong value

```
Number("580682945690490185")
580682945690490200

parseInt("580682945690490185")
580682945690490200
```

Comment: `console.log(580682945690490185)` nothing to do with the methods.

Comment: Use `BigInt`. The `Number` type is too small for this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large numbers erroneously rounded in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number is bigger than the maximum safe number as in IEEE 754 you can only safely represent numbers between -(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1.

You should try with `BigInt` which has no limit