# JSON.stringify() converts integers to exponential

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I have a record

```
           [
              "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
              1000000000000000000000
           ],
```

`JSON.stringify()`  converts it to the form

```
           [
                "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY",
                1e+21
           ],
```

`JSON.stringify()` writes it accordingly the same way, can this be somehow solved?

Comment: If you reallly want to keep it in that specific format, convert it to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` **doesn't** convert it to 1e+21, it converts it to a number that, when converted to string in the usual way, is output as the string `"1e+21"`. But the number is the same number whether you write it as `1000000000000000000000` or `1e+21`.

`JSON.stringify` may output it in either form; both are valid JSON numbers, and both define exactly the same number.

---

I should note that you need to beware of numbers of that magnitude in JavaScript (or any other language that uses IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers [or single-precision ones, actually]). That number is well into the range where even integers may be imprecisely represented. Any number greater than 9,007,199,254,740,992 (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1`) may or may not have a precise representation. It happens that 10,000,00,000,000,000,000,000 (your number) does, but for instance, 9,007,199,254,740,99**3** doesn't, nor do any odd numbers from that point upward. At some point, you get to where only multiples of 4 can be represented; and then later it's only multiple of 8, etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript)'s answers for more.

Comment: Okay, what should I do so that the output is not in exponential form?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)'s answers. I've also added a note to the answer about the magnitude of the number you're using, which is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to get `1e+21` as `1000000000000000000000`, you can use `(1e+21).toLocaleString().split(',').join('')`

but actually, you don't need to convert it if you want to use it as a number, because they are absolutely the same.

Instead, you can keep the number as string and use `+'1000000000000000000000'` or `parseInt('1000000000000000000000')` when you need to use it as a number.

Comment: `(1e+21).toLocaleString().split(',').join('')` actually converts number `1e+21` to a string `'1000000000000000000000'`

Comment: **That may or may not work, depending on locale.** Details [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tolocalestring). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript)'s answers. `(1e+21).toLocaleString().replace(/\D/g, "")` would be more reliable if you knew the number was an integer as this one is, but I wouldn't use it in production.