# Getting k6 response with JSON object that contain long integer

Tags: javascript, json, k6

I have a problem when during a performance test I get a response that contains items like

```
{"item":{"id":2733382000000000049}}
```

The k6 `response.json()` parses it as :

```
{"item":{"id":2733382000000000000}}
```

So it replaces the last digits with 0s.
Also if I try to log the `response.body()` I get:

```
ERRO[0001] TypeError: Value is not an object: {"item":{"id":2733382000000000049}}
```

The maximum integer that javascript can safely work with is much smaller:

```
> console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
9007199254740991
```

So any way to bypass this in k6 without changing the backend code?

Comment: Where does the `id` value come from? Basically, you need to [make `id` a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript) rather than a number in the JSON. Surprising if k6 itself is creating those `id`s, given that although it's written in Go it's at least JavaScript-adjacent...

Comment: The id comes as a raw response from the backend. So the only way to change it to a string is within the backend code

Comment: `So any way to bypass this in k6 without changing the backend code?` not easily ... use `response.text()` - and then write some code to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.text()` instead, then you MAY be able to do something

```js
// text would be the result of response.text()
const text = '{"item":{"id":2733382000000000049}}'
const fix = text.replace(/(\d{15,})/g, '"$1"');
console.log(JSON.parse(fix))
```

Since I have no clue about the rest of the JSON you actually get, this may well be a very naive solution.

Based on what you've shown, it would work.

Comment: Yep, already did like that. This seems to be the MWP solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX It is indeed not proper, as in not suitable for this platform, to put meta-commentary such as the one you added onto your post, as well established in the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). The arguing ends here. You can take it to Meta if this bothers you enough.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is:

Preprocessing your string from API to convert it into string before parsing.
Optionally, you could convert it back into number for your own purpose.
Here is the RegExp to convert all numbers in your string (proceeded with :) into strings:

```
 // convert all number fields into strings to maintain precision
 // : 922271061845347495, => : "922271061845347495",
 stringFromApi = stringFromApi.replace(/:\s*(-?\d+),/g, ': "$1",');
```

Regex explanation:

\s* any number of spaces 
-? one or zero '-' symbols (negative number support) 
\d+ one or more digits 
(...) will be put in the $1 variable

Comment: that's a better regex than mine :p