# Swagger UI rounds large decimal values wrongly C#

Tags: swagger

I have following value saved in Postgresql database within numeric(21,3) column: 999999999999999423.999
Property on the C# side of the application is defined as decimal.

But swagger reads this values as:
999999999999999400

Could it be caused by JS limitations or what could be the cause/fix?

Also, I included setup for swagger:
options.SerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.FloatParseHandling.Decimal

Answer (score 0):

Less likely that it's Swagger problem.
You might see this behavior due to number represented as IEEE 754 (double in C# or JS). Check this answer, he describes this affect [Large numbers erroneously rounded in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript/1379973#1379973).

When JSON converts into C# it has too large number then rounding rules might apply due to IEEE 754.

You can try in C# and you will be surprised :) :

```
double a = 999999999999999423.999;
double b = 999999999999999400;
if (a == b) Console.WriteLine("Surprise!");
```

Comment: When JSON converts into C# it has too large number then rounding rules might apply due to IEEE 754.

This is applied for decimal values also, not only for double?
decimal a = 999999999999999423.999;
decimal b = 999999999999999400;
if (a == b) Console.WriteLine("Surprise!"); -> this is false

Comment: Just for curiosity purpose, did you try to send your large decimal as string and parse it into decimal on backend side?

Comment: that works ok, I am just curious why it doesn't work with decimals.
I also tried to map properties as 
options.MapType<decimal>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "number", Format = "decimal"}); but it didn't help

Comment: Looks like it can't handle large numbers from JSON to decimal. It could be 2 things, 1) it follows the same rule for rounding; 2) Newtonsoft.Json can't convert properly numbers >15 digits

Comment: Do you know where can I find confirmation for 2) ?

Comment: I found only similar issue for Newtonsoft.Json Bson serializer https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2551