Parse string to int64
I have an issue where a string containing a 64 bit number, is being parsed by parseInt and some bits are lost in the process. my application uses ES5 and so BigInt is not available. How can I parse it as a number of 64 bit then under ES5?


str = "72057594044342942"
console.log(parseInt(str));




There are no 64 bit integers in  ES5; they simply do not exist. Your best option is to maintain the values as strings.

Because all numbers in JS are 64bit floats. You might get away with something like https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi (or any other bigint implementation)

whats the max length in ES5 for integer?

@DavidGarcia Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

@DavidGarcia - Depends on the integer. Loss of precision in integers starts after Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 (that is, after 9,007,199,254,740,992). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript Much bigger ones can be represented, but the ones adjacent to them can't. For example, 243,194,379,878,006,750 can be represented, but not the dozen or so integers before and after it. If you can't use BigInt, you'll need any of the various libraries that preceded BigInt.

if its 9 quadrillion, why is it being parsed up to 72057594044342940 (72) quadrillion, the difference is in the last two numbers only (72057594044342942 parseInt = 72057594044342940)

That's the maximum safe integer, after that there will be gaps where the rounding you're seeing happens.

If you want to introduce a new function into an older version of software, we apply so-called polyfills for that purpose.
You can also find such a thing for BigInt on the internet.
big-integer (npmjs.com)


// Original example
var str = "72057594044342942";
var bigIntNum = bigInt(str);
console.log('original', bigIntNum.toString());

// Calculate
console.log('+3', bigIntNum.add(3).toString());
console.log('-3', bigIntNum.minus(3).toString());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.52/BigInteger.min.js" integrity="sha512-9Ep9DTmyYR7ilaRntBdTgdiAWg/hDjwbkgxjt04LAZdHWdo5k0eQoxmvdjz99hPSvh7R2M2LWk3DvaWer6f9mA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



