Simple & Complex datatype in JavaScript
I was reading a difference b/w primitive and non-primitive datatype there I read primitive datatypes use simple values and non-primitive datatypes use complex value.
If I write
var a = 2736473563479857345397538528937598327
we know its a bigInt and it is obviously a primitive datatype but it is a complex number because, we are unable to read at once. So what would be the exact difference so that we instantly find out that it is a complex number.

"we know its a bigInt" no it's not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379934/large-numbers-erroneously-rounded-in-javascript and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

It's not a bigint. You have to explicitly make bigints, they aren't just created automatically if the number is large enough.

When your referenced material mentioned Complex Value for non-primitive (complex or referenced) data type, it is not saying complex because the value is big but because they can hold multiple values and are mutable.
An example of complex data type is Object, which can hold element(s) of any data type:
let student = { 
        firstName: "first", 
        lastName: "last", 
        age: 13, 
        isGraduated: true,
        graduationDate: "2024-08-09"
}

From the snippet above, the Object has values comprising a various simple  data types.
